# Use Return from while cycle

Tags: php, cycle

I find multiple topics about using `return` for a cycle. But to say true all was about the same. insert data in cycle to array and then return that array.

What I am doing is have cycle in cycle so maybe thats problem but how ever I try I can't make it work.

```
public function getSolicData() {
    foreach ($this->solicStringConvert() as $solic){
        $success = false;
        try{
            $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM solic_code WHERE manufacturer = :manufacturer_code AND main_type = :main_type AND option_code = :option_code";
            $stmt_solic = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt_solic->bindValue( "manufacturer_code", "06", PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt_solic->bindValue( "main_type", "50", PDO::PARAM_STR );            
            $stmt_solic->bindValue( "option_code", $solic, PDO::PARAM_STR );      
            $stmt_solic->execute();
            $i= 0;
            while ($row = $stmt_solic->fetch()){
                //echo $row['description'];   
                //echo '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>TEXT</li>';
                //echo '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>&nbsp;"'.$row['description'].'"</li>';   
                echo $row['description'];
                echo "<br>";                
                $this->values[] = $row['description'];
                return $this->values;            
            }
        }catch(PDOExeption $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            echo $con->errorInfo();
        }

     } 
 }
```

Code looks logic for me, unfortunately its output is blanked array. Other part of the code should be fine because if i use `echo` instead of `return` I get nice cycle output. Also if I replace "`return`" with `var_dump()` all datas are there.

Is there a chance someone can help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

return exits `getSolicData` function, so you only ever do one iteration of your loop.

Simply place the return statement at the end:

```
public function getSolicData() {
    $tempArray = $this->solicStringConvert();
    foreach ($tempArray as $key => $solic){
        $success = false;
        try{
            $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM solic_code WHERE manufacturer = :manufacturer_code AND main_type = :main_type AND option_code = :option_code";
            $stmt_solic = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt_solic->bindValue( "manufacturer_code", "06", PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt_solic->bindValue( "main_type", "50", PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt_solic->bindValue( "option_code", $tempArray[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt_solic->execute();
            $i= 0;
            while ($row = $stmt_solic->fetch()){
                //echo $row['description'];   
                //echo '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>TEXT</li>';
                //echo '<li class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>&nbsp;"'.$row['description'].'"</li>';   
                echo $row['description'];
                echo "<br>";
                $this->values[] = $row['description'];
                // NOT HERE
            }
        }catch(PDOExeption $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            echo $con->errorInfo();
        }

    }
    return $this->values; //AT THE END
}
```

Also, `bindValue` takes a reference, so you cannot use the temporay variable created in the foreach loop (it gets overwritten every iteration, so its final value will get used for all queries), instead pass the actual array element

Comment: Hey, I try it, it return me just "array" word but if i var_dump it return everything...

Comment: Oh never mind, i copy the code mate.... echo return variabiles but return not :(
I just try to removed echo and added var_dump before return:
array(17) { [0]=> string(12) "2-DVÉŘOVÝ" [1]=> string(20) "STŘEŠNÍ OKNO MECH" [2]=> string(23) "TÓNOVANÁ SKLA ZELENÁ" [3]=> string(20) "VNĚ-ZRCÁTKA NASTAV" [4]=> string(22) "BEZ ČERVENÉ OZD-LIŠ" [5]=> string(20) "REGUL SKLONU SVĚTEL" [6]=> string(13) "POTAHY LÁTKA" [7]=> string(18) "SEDADLO L V-NASTAV" [8]=> string(22) "ČALOUN PŘÍSTR-DESKY" [9]=> string(14) "1,8 L 66KW RP" [10]=> string(17) "PŘEVOD 4+E-RYCHL" [11]=> string(14) ..

Comment: Hmm, well return just sends the variable back to the calling function. How is the calling function handling the return value?

Comment: `<li class=\"list-group-item\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success\"></span>&nbsp;LOKÁTOR/KAMERA</li>                        
                        ".$this->getSolicData()."`  everything is in one echo of course :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest moving the `return $this->values;` at the end of the method because when the `return` statement is encountered it returns the current value of `$this->values` and nothing more from that method is executed afterwards.